# asp.net javascript Always open single instance of application from email link

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am working on an application (asp.net) where links to my application go through an email. Now one of the requirements is that only one instance of the application must be open for a user. Now when a user clicks on a link from an email I want to be able to spot if my application is already open in one of the browsers, grab it, change location and focus on that. Expecting it to be a javascript solution.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that is impossible, sorry.

Comment: If its not possible, whats the conventional way this scenario works for some other applications ???. I need it to be a single instance application as part of CFR Part 11 Compliance